# Restricting concurrent http request access in Spring based application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web

I need to restrict multiple access to a single functionality or http request or method using Spring MVC or any spring technologies.

For example, I have a movie booking system, where in I need to restrict simultaneous booking of a particular seat.So If a particular user opts for particular seat in a movie and checks out, and if another user opts for a same seat I need to inform second user that its already filled.

I am thinking to use JMS in a synchronous manner.But not sure whether its a good approach or any other simpler ways to implement the functionality.

If we are using JMS then, do we need generate one queue for each movie or single queue is sufficient for whole application.

Any thoughts on this will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve your purpose by JMS but actually its purpose is totally different. Your problem is data modification by concurrent request. The best way to prevent is Optimistic Locking. Use version to your tables and that will ease your life.

See [Hibernate Version For Optimistic Locking](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/versioning-optimistic-locking-in-hibernate/)